# What problem does backbone.js solve?

Tags: backbone.js

When I gloss over the backbone.js site, I'm not sure what is it trying to do.

It seems somewhat popular, but why should I want to learn it? What will it do for me? Why was it made? What problem does it solve?

Comment: Suppose you have someone's avatar displayed in ten different places on a page and one of those places changes the avatar, backbone will broadcast this change to the other places that care so that things will sync up again. The data/model events are the biggest benefit I see. Voted to close though.

Comment: hm, why not write that into an answer? And why vote to close?

Comment: It's not intended to mock it or anything. I expect people who know backbone and use it to explain what it's all about.

Comment: Using this question's answers to make the claim that backbone is pointless ([as you have undeniably done](https://gun.io/blog/backbone-vs-knockout/)) is extremely questionable.  You asked a broad & general question, so you got broad & general answers.  Normally I'm supportive of broad questions on SO, but you're giving fuel to support the question closers.

Comment: Whoa, I made that comment long long after writing the question and receiving the answers for it. It's not like I asked the question purposely to make it sound pointless.

Comment: My criticism still stands.  I didn't say "asking the question for the purpose of making the claim..." I said "using this question's answers to make the claim..."

Answer (score 17):

I find the question perfectly valid and from my point of view there is nothing wrong with inquiring about the potential use cases of a library/toolkit.

What Backbone.js does (so do several other javascript mvc implementations) is that it provides a means of organizing the code into a modular pattern known as MVC pattern which is all about separating your code into three loosely coupled layers:

- Model layer dealing purely with data and associated operations
- View layer being the presentational aspects
- Controller layer being the binding glue layer

(different frameworks deal with this differently : Backbone implementation of controller layer comprises of client side routing capabilities).

So, on the whole backbone provides you an infrastructure using which you can deal with data through models which contain encapsulated within them the data and associated validations, which can be observed ie. you can bind events to change events.

The View layer is mostly left for the user to separate the ui into manageable isolated sections.

Answer (score 13):

Here are some problems that Backbone solves for me in the JS/HTML space:

- [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) (SoC)
- [Composability](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~Compose/)
- [Testability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testability)
- [Component Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component-based_software_engineering)
- [Abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_%28computer_science%29)

That is not to say that this is the ONLY system that does this.  There are others.  Backbone does a pretty good job of helping with these things, though.

Comment: any examples for each of above mentioned things please?

Answer (score 4):

From backbonejs.org

> It's all too easy to create JavaScript applications that end up as
>   tangled piles of jQuery selectors and callbacks

And that's exactly what backbone does, a series of callbacks on model changes and jQuery selectors to bind events.

So to answer the question, it solves nothing only to provide a way (the backbone way) of structuring code with some slight automation in the REST side of things.

Comment: From my point of view, Backbone *Views* are still a bit of a mess of jQuery (or similar) DOM manipulation. I'm currently trying to figure out a way of combining Backbone Models and Collections with [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com) data bindings which, in my opinion, are a great example of a more declarative approach to describing changes to the DOM. I've discovered [Knockback](http://kmalakoff.github.io/knockback/), but documentation is confusing and scarce, and I'm afraid to commit to three different frameworks for the basics.

Comment: Forget backbone, knockout, Knockback and almost all frameworks, bar AngularJS. One framework, most bases covered, auto loading of html partials, plain js objects for data binding. No need to create strange observables and observable arrays which in once instance you get the value from by calling it as a function, in another instance you reference it like an object property. AngularJS is very easy once you get over the initial learning curve, gives your code great structure, has no opinion of what the backend is / should be. I'm no fan of JS frameworks in general but Angular really is great.

Comment: Fair point. Angular looks like it has a lot of the parts I love about frameworks. Unfortunately, 10% of the users of the app I'm currently building are still on IE8 and numbers are dropping very slowly. As I understand, non-ES5 browser support in Angular was stopped some time ago. Using Knockout plugins you can enhance the library a decent amount. Knockout Punches gives you `{{ expressions | and | filters: woo }}` and Knockout-ES5 prevents you from having to get values by calling them as functions, however that is only supported in browsers with `defineProperty` support which is non-shimmable.

Comment: Angular 1.2.x fully supports IE8, use `$sceProvider.enabled(false);` if running on IE8 throws errors. You might not get to use Angular 1.3, but 1.2 is and will continue to be superior to everything else.